# Inserting into DB sometimes doesn´t work (chat with PDO, AJAX, long polling)

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have chat that uses long polling to get messages from DB (there are no problems to load them). But i also have script that insert messages into DB and it sometimes doesnt work ... it just doesn´t insert the row but it says that it was inserted.

```
<?php
include_once "../conect.php";     
$sprava = $_POST['sprava'];       // received message 
session_start(); 
echo $sprava; 
$ja = $_SESSION['id'];
session_write_close();
$cas = time();

try { 
    $conn = new PDO($databaza, $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query = "SELECT som FROM user WHERE id = :ja";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':ja', $ja, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if ($stmt->execute()) echo "works ";
} 
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$on = $row["som"];
echo $on;
if ($on == "") return 0;

try { 
    $conn = new PDO($databaza, $username, $password); 
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $query = "INSERT INTO chat (cas,text,od,pre) VALUES (:cas, :text, :od, :pre)"; 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->bindValue(':cas', $cas, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $stmt->bindValue(':text', $sprava, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':od', $ja, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':pre', $on, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
    if ($affected_rows == 1) echo " works";
}
catch(PDOException $e) { 
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();} 
?>
```

i get no errors and outpus is still in form as it should be 
for example

```
1 works 37 works
2 works 37 works
3 works 37 works
4 works 37 works
5 works 37 works
```

that first number is message I entered, the first "works" means that ID of user was loaded, the second nuber is loaded ID and the last "works" means that the message was inserted into DB but it sometimes wasn´t (just sometimes).

but in DB i have rows only with for example

```
1
2
4
```

and 3, 5 is missing

Comment: What does the pdo error tell you?

Comment: there are no errors ... it just doesnt insert some rows

Comment: I think you should re-write everything, because I see many flaws in your code. I would say 70% of what you have written is purely bad code, and that is where the problem is. I can tell this, because I have created a chat script using PDO, but I can't understand the way you are writting it

Answer (score 0):

An `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger is doing this. Check your table's triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning 0 when `$on` is empty, when this happens , it won't insert the data

If you are going to SELECT an INSERT in the same script, then I suggest you to split that logic especially if the INSERT depend on what the SELECT returns.

Create 2 fucntions:

**SELECT function**

```
function select_som($conn, $ja){
    try { 
        $query = "SELECT som FROM user WHERE id = :ja";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(':ja', $ja, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $success = $stmt->execute();
        if(!$success){
            echo "SELECT failed";
        }
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        $on = $row["som"];
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $on;
}
```

**INSERT function**

```
function insert_data($conn, $cas, $sprava, $ja, $on){
    try { 
        $query = "INSERT INTO chat (cas,text,od,pre) VALUES (:cas, :text, :od, :pre)"; 
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->bindValue(':cas', $cas, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $stmt->bindValue(':text', $sprava, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':od', $ja, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':pre', $on, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) { 
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
  return $affected_rows;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
if(isset($_POST['sprava'])){
    include_once "../conect.php"; 
    //session
    session_start(); 
    $ja = $_SESSION['id'];
    session_write_close();
    //connection
    $conn = new PDO($databaza, $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //get "$on"
    $on = select_som($conn, $ja);
    //insert
    if($on != ""){
        $cas = time();
        $sprava = $_POST['sprava'];
        $success = insert_data($conn, $cas, $sprava, $ja, $on);
        if($success==1){
            echo "INSERT Successful";
        }else{
            echo "INSERT Failed!!";
        }
    }else{
        echo "on is empty, cannot insert data";
    }
}
```